# how can i take wordpress post as embed?

Tags: posts, the-content, post-content

how can i get an adress for using iframe in another website?

Example:

```
site.com/sample-page
```

i will use this page in another website as iframe

but only content part

Example:

```
<iframe src="site.com/sample-page/iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can’t. That’s now how iframes work. The other website would need to provide their own way for you to do this.

Comment: i will share my web site with iframe

Comment: If the site you are trying to "embed" is a WordPress site, it would work much better to pull its content via the REST API. It would take some coding, but then you'd have the content directly and wouldn't have all the resize/responsive issues of iframes.